# :nth-child(even) не работает Angular компонентах

Tags: css, angular2, компоненты

Имею компоненты ангуляр

```
<app-list-items>
   <app-item></app-item>
   <app-item></app-item>
   <app-item></app-item>
   <app-item></app-item>
</app-list-items>
```

Шаблон для компонент примитивный

**list-items.component.html**

```
<div>
    <ng-content select="app-item"></ng-content>
</div>
```

**item.component.html**

```
<p class="test">hell WORLD!!!!!</p>
```

**list-items.component.css**

```
 p:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: black;
    color:floralwhite;
 }

 p:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:floralwhite;
    color: red;
 }
 p {
   border-top: 1px solid black;
 }

 p:first-child{
   border-top: none;
 }
```

Ну и по итогу наблюдаю что контекст для разметки компонента локализуется и он все теги p считает первыми и единственными. Как заставить работать селекторы first-child|last-child, nth-child()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете отключить инкапсуляцию стилей, добавив `ViewEncapsulation.None` в родительском компоненте:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-list-items",
  styleUrls: ["list-items.component.css"],
  templateUrl: "list-items.component.html",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ListItems {
...
}
```

И тогда стили можно прописывать для дочерних компонентов, но стили начинать надо с родительского селектора

```
app-list-items p {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Или же, вы можете не отключать инкапсуляцию стилей, а просто добавить эти стили в глобальную таблицу `styles.css`